# Where is my NSTableView in NSScrollView?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nstableview

Why in Xcode 4 (i don't kwow in 3.2) when i drag and drop a table from interface builder it became `NSScrollView`? Where is `NSTableView`??? (**NSTableView in NSScrollView**)

How can i access `NSTableView` from `NSScrollView`?

How can i `add` a row, `delete`, `customize` and `RELOAD DATA`?

---

Why if i do

```
for (id obj in scrollView.subviews)
  NSLog(@"obj: %@", obj);
```

i don't able to get NSTableView description?

thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

XCode automatically embeds the table in a scroll view for you. To select your Table View you can either slowly double click on the Scroll View, press control+shift and click on the Scroll View, or click the right-facing triangle under the vertical objects in the XIB to reveal every object in the XIB.

You can access it programatically by calling [scrollView documentView], because it is technically a subview of the ScrollView's Content View (an instance of NSClipView)

To populate your table view you can provide content by hooking up a data source, or by binding its table columns to an array controller.

It's kind of complicated, you should probably take a look at the [Documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/TableView/Introduction/Introduction.html)

Comment: Well, `[scrollView.documentView reloadData]` is perfect! thanks.

Answer (score 5):

To access the `tableview` just connect the `tableview` with the code `(IBOutlet NSTableview *yourTableview)` then access it easily like `[yourTableview reloadData];` Dont bother about the `scrollview`

Answer (score 0):

Inside "Bordered Scroll View" there is a "Clip View" and inside there is a "Table View". This one you need to connect with your code.